# XSLT :: Nodelist to string

Tags: xslt

my input xml is

```
<Country name="myCountry>
 <City>city1</City>
 <City>city2</City>
 <City>city3</City>
</Country>
```

I am trying to write xslt(2.0) to get back the output in this format

```
<AllCities>city1|city2|city3</AllCities>
```

This is what i tried

```
<xsl:template match="Country">
 <xsl:value-of select="City"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Below is what I get which is pretty close, but what is the most efficient (least code) way to append all elements with a pipe (Except the last one)?

```
city1city2city3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<xsl:template match="Country">
    <AllCities>
        <xsl:value-of select="City" separator="|"/>
    </AllCities>
</xsl:template>
```